# Realistic clone tank design for long-term post-mortem effects

Tags: science-based, biology, science-fiction, decay

Let's say you have your stereotypical sci-fi/video game clone tanks: people, in translucent goo (preferably glowing), grown to physical maturity in a glass container. Let's presume the tanks are initially sealed and sterile, and the goo is some kind of biological growth medium. You were using them to grow a clone army in your underground base. (Luckily, the clones were input to a process that produced cyborg soldiers, so you didn't need healthy adult brains. Why clones? Because the mad scientist designing this process was a twisted egomaniac, they're all clones of him. Also this way no one complaints about the mysterious orphan shortage. Practicality was very much a secondary concern.) Then pesky heroes came in and blew up parts of the base, cutting off power entirely and ending all maintenance. Five centuries later, brave adventurers discover your old clone factory.

Is there a remotely reasonable growth medium that would result in the tank contents being recognizable five hundred years after the plug is effectively pulled? (Recognizable = at least bones; mummies or perfectly preserved bodies are fine but seem unlikely to my limited understanding.) I've found lots of information on decay in open environments, or very dry ones, and I'm familiar with the effects of deliberate preservation, but the long term combination of closed-wet-and-sterile isn't something I could find information about, and without any deliberate preservation it seems like it should result in *some* kind of chemical degradation over time even if nothing's technically rotting.

If it's relevant, the base itself is well-sealed, dry, and has minimal to no air movement, which to the best of my understanding means that most objects that are part of or outside the tanks should be extremely fragile and have mostly-minor structural failures over time but be overall recognizable. (The glass, presumably, will be just fine.) I'm assuming that therefore the tank itself is unlikely to disintegrate before the contents reach some kind of steady state, but if I'm wrong I'd love to know.

Comment: You got this idea from the Snoke jar in the Rise of Skywalker, didn't you?

Comment: Oddly enough, no! I'm doing a far-future fic set in the Final Fantasy XV universe. (Which, well-- final fantasy is not known for its consistent magical *or* physical principles, but I'm doing my best anyway.)

Comment: *"Tech undefined"* implies than five centuries later the brave adventurers will find whatever the plot wants them to find.

Comment: Without the underlying mechanisms defined, the question is A. Too Broad (too many possible explanations for what is in the environment/tanks) B. Opinion Based (I could literally name any clear liquid if I add enough green dye) C. If I could answer and have it declined because "it doesn't fit the story" but no such limit is stated its probably "Primarily Story Based" (or if the only difference between answers would be story)

Comment: I would split this into multiple specific questions like, "What liquid would fit for being in a cloning vat but looks green?", "In a climate controlled base, what would a 5 century old corpse look like?" "Would Liquid A from the previous accepted answer preserve an organic body inside?"